# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Here i have a functionality where after a user register to my site it will redirect to path ('user.show').User can also search for another user in the url.If the user exist ('user.show') will provide the requested user's information.But if user search for an invalid name it will provide the current logged in user( the user who is searching ) information.When i attempt for a invalid user i get the error.The error is in the following line

```
$info=User::where($indicator,'=', Auth::user()->$indicator)->get()->first();
```

**Show() method in user controller :**

```
public function show($user)
    {
        //
        $indicator=is_numeric($user)?'user_id':'username';
        $info=User::where($indicator,'=',$user)->get()->first();
        if($info){
           echo 'bal';
           $data=array('info'=>$info);
           return View::make('user.show')->with('info',$data);
        }else{
          echo "this user doesn't exist";

          $info=User::where($indicator,'=', Auth::user()->$indicator)->get()->first();

          $data=array('info'=>$info);
          return View::make('user.show')->with('info',$data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `$indicator` returns when you're trying to call `Auth::user()->$indicator`?

Comment: it seems like Auth::user()->$indicator not a valid object...it gives me error if i echo Auth::user()->$indicator

Comment: Check what does `dd($indicator);` returns.

Comment: returns 'username'

Comment: dd(Auth::user()->$indicator) returns error..i think the problem is in Auth ??

Comment: dd( Auth::user) is null

Comment: Just jecked, it should work, but `Auth::user()` has `name` instead of `username`. I'm using built-in Laravel 5.2 authentication system.

Comment: Then what i should do here?

Comment: Try to `dd(Auth:user());` and open up `attributes`. You'll see a list of available attributes. Is there `username` or `name` in the list?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then my original answer is correct. It's a situation when visitor did not log in and he's searching for non-existing user. `if(Auth::user())` will check for current user (is there logged in user or not).

Comment: There is a logged in user and he/her might search for another user..this is the situation...I have an Auth::attempt functionality which works fine

Comment: Well, if `Auth:user()` is null, that means there is no logged in user. You should check your authentication system, because something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(Auth::user()){
    // User is authenticated
    $info = User::where($indicator,'=', Auth::user()->$indicator)->get()->first();
}else{
    // User is not authenticated
}
```

Instead of this:

```
$info=User::where($indicator,'=', Auth::user()->$indicator)->get()->first();
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is ,if searched user doesn't exist it will return the logged in user

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(Auth::check()){
    $info = User::where($indicator,'=', Auth::user()->$indicator)->first();
}else{
   // Other code goes hr
}
```

Comment: dd(Auth::user()) is NULL..what i should do?

Comment: where did you put the dd(Auth::user()). is it inside the if condition?

Comment: What do you want to do if there is no authenticated user?

Comment: There is a logged in user and he/her might search for another user..this is the situation..if searched user is not available it will retirve information about logged in user .....I have an Auth::attempt functionality which works fine

Comment: meaning the other part of the if condition that is the **else** part should never trigger.

Comment: else should trigger if someone types a wrong username..say i am logged in  under usernaem "mrX" if i search "myY" which doesnot exist it should return "mrX" instead